# Is the following allowed?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Consider any two collections of sets $A=\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$ and $B=\{B_1,\ldots,B_m\}$ where the following holds:

$$\sum_{x\in A}|x|=\sum_{y\in B}|y|$$

Is it true that this statement is the same as

$$\sum_{x\in A}|x|-\sum_{y\in B}|y|=0$$

?

When talking about finite cardinalities it is vacuously true, but what about infinite sizes? It is not clear to me.

Comment: What is $x$? Is it a subset of $A_i\subseteq A$ for some $i$?

Comment: And what is $-$ ?

Comment: $x$ is just a set $A_i\in A$

Comment: - is regular subtraction. And |.| is the cardinality of a set

Comment: @Garmekain Subtraction is not well-defined for infinite cardinals. For example, the equation $\aleph_0 + \kappa=\aleph_0$ is true for all finite $\kappa$ as well as for $\kappa=\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $e_1=e_2$ is the same as $e_1-e_2=0$, as long as $e_1$ and $e_2$ are expressions with definite values in a structure where subtraction makes sense. Then it doesn't matter if $e_1$ and $e_2$ are infinite sums or other complicated things involving limits *internally*.

However, it sounds like the values of your expressions are *infinite cardinals*, which are *not* a domain where subtraction makes sense. If that is the case, then the second equations is ill-defined and *therefore* not equivalent to the first one.

(What you *also can't* do, at least without being quite careful, is rewrite your second equation to
$$ \Biggl ( \sum_{x\in A\cup B}\begin{cases} |x| & \text{for }x\in A \\ -|x| & \text{for }x\in B\end{cases} \Biggr) = 0 $$
even if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.)